# how to identify range in EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is there no way to do sth like this in EPPlus

```
var r = ws.Cells["myRange"];
```

so I can identify a range and find out its location?

Start cell and start column.

Comment: Why do you want to know? (If you want to do something to the cells in the range, you don't need to know their absolute coordinates)

Comment: What kind of range is "myRange"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a range in excel and tried to "get" it from the code using worksheet.Cells["myNamedRange"] - doesnt work

Comment: var x= from cell in ws.Cells["b2:c13"]
                            where cell.Value.ToString() == "textToSearch"
                            select cell;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
ExcelNamedRange myRange = worksheet.Names["RangeName"];
int startRow = myRange.Start.Row;
int startCol = myRange.Start.Column;
int endRow = myRange.End.Row;
int endCol = myRange.End.Column;
```

You can also try

```
string address=myRange.Address;
string fullAddress= myRange.FullAddress;
string absAddress=myRange.FullAddressAbsolute;
```